# JavaScript ES6 inline object literal create logic

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Is there anyway to rewrite the following **ES6** JavaScript to not require a temporary storage variable `data`?

```
const data = {};

if(error) {
    data.error = error;
} else {
    data.response = 'some response here';
}

res.json(200, data);
```

I'd like to just be able to inline the object to `res.json()`:

```
res.json(200, {
    // inline logic that is identical to above
});
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you could use ternary operator

```
res.json(200, error ? {error} : {response: 'some response here'});
```

Comment: no es6 allows you to write it like that if the key and the variable that contains the value is the same. `{error} === {error: error}`